# decimate 3D mesh with colors

Tags: 3d, mesh, meshlab, simplification

I'm using Meshlab software to decimate 3D meshes. This works fine, however when I want to decimate a 3D mesh with colors on vertices, I don't know which algorithm to use since no one is presented managing colors (MC Edge collapse, Clustering Decimation, Quadric Edge Collapse Decimation). Any advice for decimating 3D mesh with colors? 
Also, I will be interested if you know some code doing that. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the experience about this.

First, train a KNN model for origin mesh

Second, downsample origin mesh to mesh2

Third, use KNN model to predict the mesh2 label

```
    from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
    import vedo
    import numpy as np

    mesh = vedo.load(your_3Dobject_path)
    neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
    neigh.fit(mesh.cellCenters(), np.ravel(mesh.getCellArray('Label')))
    
    #downsample to 1000
    target_num = 1000
    ratio = target_num/mesh.NCells() # calculate ratio
    mesh2 = mesh.clone()
    mesh2.decimate(fraction=ratio)
    
    fine_labels = neigh.predict(mesh2.cellCenters())
    fine_labels = fine_labels.reshape(-1, 1)
    mesh2.addCellArray(fine_labels, 'Label')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute vertex attributes like color when doing edge collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

Another example similar to Huang's one could be:

```py
from vedo import Sphere

# a test mesh
s = Sphere().lw(1)

# points as numpy array
pts = s.points()
# associate a scalar to each mesh vertex
# and set its color by a standard colormap
s.cmap("rainbow", pts[:,0]).print()

s.decimate(method='pro')
s.smooth() #optionally smooth the mesh

s.show(axes=1)
```

[image]